# Python: selecting sentence based on given words and export them as excel

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

let say, I have the following paragraph as string:

```
str=You can also use negative index numbers to slice a string. As we went through before, negative index numbers of a string start at -1, and count down from there until we reach the beginning of the string. When using negative index numbers, we’ll start with the lower number first as it occurs earlier in the string.
```

I want to find a sentence that contains the word `input words= 'negative' and 'string'`. And list them in separate `str` of each sentence. For example, I am expected to get output

```
negative= a) You can also use negative index numbers to slice a string.
          b ) As we went through before, negative index numbers of a string start at -1, and count down from there until we reach the beginning of the string. 
          c) When using negative index numbers, we’ll start with the lower number first as it occurs earlier in the string.
string= a) You can also use negative index numbers to slice a string
        b) As we went through before, negative index numbers of a string start at -1, and count down from there until we reach the beginning of the string.
        c) When using negative index numbers, we’ll start with the lower number first as it occurs earlier in the string.
```

As you can see all sentences contains both 'negative' and 'string' words, hence includes all sentences.

If there is any way to do this without using `for loop` or in a simple way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest splitting your string to get each sentence first. Then, check if the words are contained in each sentence.

To store each list into an Excel file, you will need to install [pandas](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/) first.

```sh
$ pip install pandas
```

You might also need to install [openpyxl](https://pypi.org/project/openpyxl/).

```sh
$ pip install openpyxl
```

Here's how you can achieve this result:

```py
import pandas as pd

huge_sentence = "You can also use negative index numbers to slice a string. As we went through before, negative index numbers of a string start at -1, and count down from there until we reach the beginning of the string. When using negative index numbers, we’ll start with the lower number first as it occurs earlier in the string."

sentences = huge_sentence.split(".")

sentence_with_negative_word = [sentence + "." for sentence in sentences if "negative" in sentence]
sentence_with_string_word = [sentence + "." for sentence in sentences if "string" in sentence]

# Now, we export each list in a different Excel file
pd.DataFrame(sentence_with_negative_word).to_excel('negative.xlsx', header=False, index=False)
pd.DataFrame(sentence_with_string_word).to_excel('string.xlsx', header=False, index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a great help. But, how can you export these sentences in excel? I mean sentences related to 'negative' saved in excel1 and sentences related to 'string' saved in excel2 names?

Comment: I've updated my answer to add the result to Excel files. Hope it helps